# Gulp - How To Get Parent Directory Name

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

Say I have the following website structure:

```
wwwroot
---- css
-------- clientA
------------ styles.css
-------- clientB
-------- clientC

assets
---- sass
-------- clientA
------------ styles.scss
-------- clientB
-------- clientC
```

In gulp, I want to watch the sass files in each of the folders under "assets/sass" (clientA, clientB, clientC, etc.) and write the compiled .css files to their corresponding client folder in wwwroot (same name).

So, I'm using gulp.watch to watch for changes to the sass client folders, and I'm thinking of using a callback with event.path to determine which file I'm saving:

```
gulp.watch(sassWatchFiles, function(event) {

    // get path of the file we've just saved
    var file = event.path;

    // determine the name of the parent directory
    var parentDirectory = ????; // how do I get this?

    // call sass compile method (user-defined), passing in client directory name
    compileSass(client);

});
```

In the middle line of the gulp.watch callback function, how do I get the parent directory?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_cache_callback

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - sorry, I'm confused - I can't figure out how I can use fs.realpath() to get the parent directory. My context is a gulpfile.js, if that helps - I'm not sure how to use node fs in a gulpfile.js file.

Comment: gulpfile is a normal JavaScript file, you can use any of the node modules, and any "normal" code that you'd like. Using `fs.realpath()` with conjunction with `'../'` will work just fine.

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Very good. I suppose I could also use a JavaScript regular expression to parse out the parent directory. But probably `fs.realpath()` would be more robust. Thanks.